# Variable login in cypress with fixture

Tags: authentication, cypress

I have a fixture that looks something like this:

```
{
  "field": [
    {
      "1": {
        "admin": {
          "place": "For Admins",
          "email": "admin@gmail.com",
          "password": "admin123"
        },
        "normal": {
          "place": "Normal",
          "email": "normal@gmail.com",
          "password": "normal123"
        },
        "superAdmin": {
          "email": "superAdmin@gmail.com",
          "password": "superAdmin123"
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "admin": {
          "place": "For Admins",
          "email": "admin@gmail.com",
          "password": "admin123"
        },
        "normal": {
          "place": "Normal",
          "email": "normal@gmail.com",
          "password": "normal123"
        },
        "superAdmin": {
          "email": "superAdmin@gmail.com",
          "password": "superAdmin123"
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "admin": {
          "place": "For Admins",
          "email": "admin@gmail.com",
          "password": "admin123"
        },
        "normal": {
          "place": "Normal",
          "email": "normal@gmail.com",
          "password": "normal123"
        },
        "superAdmin": {
          "email": "superAdmin@gmail.com",
          "password": "superAdmin123"
        }
      },
      "common": {
        "wrong_email": "wrong-email@gmail.com",
        "wrong_password": "wrong"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I go trough each of those `email` and `password` to have a Login validation for all ?

Like:

```
it("Successful Login", function () {
   login(email, password) {
      cy.visit("/");
      cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(email);
      cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(password);
});
```

Not sure if I need a clear fixture

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't split up your fixture, but I would use seperate `it()` blocks for each visit because Cypress is a bit fussy about multiple visits in a single test.

Using individual tests per login means you get a clean page for each login.

If you use `require()` to read the logins file, you can dynamically create individual tests.

You json is a bit complicated, so this is a for-instance to give you the idea.

```js
const logins = require('../fixtures/logins.json')

logins.field[0]['1'].entries().forEach((key,data) => {
  // key will be "admin", "normal", "superAdmin"

  it(`Testing "${key}"`, () => {
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(data.email);
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(data.password);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The fixture path is for a file path.
It is not for traversing a data structure.

`/fixture/field/1` should contain a file called `admin.json` with the following

```
{
  "place": "For Admins",
  "email": "admin@gmail.com",
  "password": "admin123"
}
```

then replicate this pattern to match what you have above
then call it like this

```
    it("Successful Login", function () {
      cy.fixture('field/1/admin').then(({ email, password }) => {
        cy.visit("/");
        cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(email);
        cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(password);
   });
```

Comment: That way, I'll not be able to test everything at the same `it`. I'll need to create a validation for each field/1

Comment: It returns whatever is in the json, if you really wanted to, I assume that you could just make a folder called users in fixtures. Then put your existing large fixture file inside, it should return the entire thing and then use it like that

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to test/validate login flow with different username and password could you try this fixture.

```
loginCreds.json
{
    "admin@gmail.com": "admin123",
    "normal@gmail.com": "normal123",
    "superAdmin@gmail.com": "superAdmin123",
    "wrong-email@gmail.com": "wrong"
 }
```

And call it in your spec file and use Object.keys to get the keys as array and access the username value through array and password value through json object.

```
    let credentials = require('../../fixtures/loginCreds');
    //Note: While adding path name in require select 'fixtures' and 'loginCreds' from auto suggestion 
    let usernames = Object.keys(credentials);
    //usernames will contain array ["admin@gmail.com","normal@gmail.com","superAdmin@gmail.com,"wrong-email@gmail.com"]  

Now we can use this array and json object stored in credentials to test login with different username and password using forEach and adding the test inside a function and calling the function in forEach

usernames.forEach (validateLogin);

function validateLogin (user) {
   describe(`Validate user ${user} can login `, () => {
    it("Successful Login", function () {
   
          cy.visit("/");
//user will be element in array "admin@gmail.com"
          cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(user); 
//credentials[user] will be value of key "admin@gmail.com" which is "admin123"
          cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(credentials[user]);
   
        );
    }
}
```

forEach will iterate over the array and call the function for every element in array and thereby tests login for different key value pairs of username and passwords.